# Bluetooth- exchanging data without using server/client relationship

Tags: android, networking, bluetooth

I'm making an app using bluetooth, and I realized it'd be pretty neat to exchange data between 2 running devices via bluetooth. 
However, as far as I know most Bluetooth devices use a traditional server/client architecture, so the information exchange is one sided, ie, client requests data from server, server sends it, but not the other way around.

To get around this problem, I tried to make each device have a server instance as well as a client instance, so that the client can hook up the the server in the other device. However this does not seem efficient as this requires 2 channels of communication instead of one.

Then I tried going to Bluetooth website, and they suggested "role switching", that is, when server wants some data from client, server makes itself a client and client becomes a server, so the role is reversed. I don't quite like it either, because why can't 2 devices play the same role and exchange data at the same time? What kind of connection is this called then?

I have not had experience in networking so my question might seem naive, but I'd like to have someone point out the answer, or tell me what information/which chapters of textbook I'm missing so I can wiki it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role switching affects the underlying Bluetooth topology: which device is master in the piconet.  That can have implications for the quality of your connection, but it does not directly affect the direction of communication in the way that you are imagining: it is at a much lower level.

Yes, in Android Bluetooth comm is done using sockets abstraction and the setup of the socket connection is done in a client-server manner.  But once the socket is connected both sides have a BluetoothSocket instance and I'm pretty sure that both sides can get an output stream and initiate communication.  What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: It's because I was reading on an API called BlueCove and I found no way of actively requesting for data from server to client. I probably just misread some pages. I'll take another look at it. thanks